# andengine polygon body and box2d collision

Tags: android, box2d, game-engine, andengine, andengine-gles-2

I recently changed my bodies from rectangle to polygons
and got a weird bug and I can't figure it out why its happening.
When my "player" body touch another body - with a negative angle he just stack on it.

My player X velocity is always constant 5

when I'm switching the body back to rectangle it working fine

[image]

Does any one fimiliar with this bug? or have any idea what can cause it?

Comment: I untagged this from google-app-engine as it is not related to google-app-engine!

Comment: Make sure your polygon is wound counter-clockwise. Use the debug draw display so you can see what the engine is really doing.

Comment: This picture is +- after using the "AndEngineDebugDrawExtension"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a bug in andengine:

When I put 3 point in the same button line this will cause the bug I write above:

To fix that you need to make sure that on evry line on the poligon there are only 2 points!

Works fine now :)